# PowerShell isn't saving configuration

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change the color of errors in the PowerShell by this command:

```
$host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = 'Cyan'
```

when typing

```
$host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor
```

I do get the output to be "Cyan", but if I relaunch it's going back to "Red" again.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't save runtime configuration on exit.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put that statement into your PowerShell profile. There are at least six possibilities for the file name; you should see [this Scripting Guy column](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) to determine which one to use. (I say 'at least' six because if you have some third-party PowerShell-enabled programs, they use their own profiles, as well.)